# Modern UI Metro Chart - Separador de milhar

Tags: wpf

Estou gerando alguns gráficos usando [Modern UI Metro Chart](https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/106190), porém em um dos gráficos o número precisaria ser mostrado com separador de milhar.

Pesquisando eu encontrei essa discussão: [Add thousand separator](https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/discussions/648960) e tentei fazer a alteração mas sem sucesso.

Tentei a alteração abaixo:

```
<Style x:Key="NumberStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" >
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2 0 2 0" />
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.75" />
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding StringFormat=N}" />
</Style>
```